# What does "let () = " mean in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, let

There are codes like

```
let () = print_string "something" in
fn
```

in some OCaml codes.

What does this mean? Is there special meaning on "()"? or Is it same meaning as

```
print_string "something";
fn
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use `let _ = ...` exclusively however as it will work for most if not all expressions.

Comment: `let _ = ...`, or fragile pattern matching, is absolutely not recommended. It's pretty much equivalent to giving a middle finger to the type system.

Comment: I agree with nlucaroni. if you want `let _ = ... in ...`, then you probably want `ignore (...); ...`

Answer (score 15):

There's nothing special about `()` in this `let` expression, it's just a pattern.  All `let` expressions look like `let` *`pattern`* `=` *`expression`* `in` *`other-expression`*.  Here the pattern will always match, because `print_string` returns `unit`, and `()` is the only value of that type.  In this way, it's just another way of combining two expressions into one when the first one is really more of a statement (returns `unit`).

So you're right, the construct has pretty much the same meaning as using the `;` operator.  The only real difference is in the precedence.  If, for example, you write

```
if x < 3 then
    print_string "something";
    f x
```

you would find that `f x` is *always* called.  The precedence of `;` is too low to pull the second expression under the control of the `if`.  That's the reason many people (including me) get into the habit of using `let () =` *`expression`*.  If you write the above as

```
if x < 3 then
    let () = print_string "something"
    in f x
```

the `f x` is only called when `x` is less than 3, which is usually what I want.  In essence, the precedence of `let` is much higher than `;`.

Of course there are may other ways to get this effect, but the nice thing about using `let` is that you don't have to add anything later on in the code (like a closing parenthesis or an `end`).  If you're adding the `print_string` as a debugging statement, this is a handy way of keeping the changes local to the one spot.

Comment: As another example of surprising program allowed by the syntax, if you only want to execute `f()` when the usual laws of arithmetic hold, you can write `let 4 = 2 + 2 in f() ;;`

Answer (score 3):

Jeffrey's answer is absolutely correct, but one more point:

if you write

```
fx "something";
fn
```

And you messed up the result type of `fx "something"` the compiler will emit a Warning, that might get lost during compilation. On the other hand if you write:

```
let () = fx "something" in
fn
```

The compiler will type check that the result of `fx "something"` can be matched against `()`, i.e. that it is really of type `unit`. Thus if you messed up an error is produced, which is usually more secure.

There also is the possibility to write

```
let _ = fx "something" in
fn
```

which will only get the precedence effect that Jeffrey mentioned, but not do any type checking, since `_` can be matched against values of any type.

Comment: and that last one is equivalent to `ignore (fx "something"); fn` in semicolon notation